# using Negative values for a box plot (box whisker)

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am drawing a box plot for a question where the data set is the bulb life time(in hours)

My 5 number summary is

```
Q1  : 208.25
Q2  : 297
Q3  : 376.5
min : 172
max : 1020

IQR : 168.25
3/2 * IQR : 252.375
```

> Upper Bound : 628.875
>   Lower Bound : -44.125

Since the data set is about time, I know I can not use negative values,so what should I use as my negative value, I know I won't get any outliers here but still I'm curious.

Comment: This does not seem a situation in which a boxplot is a helpful descriptive graphic. If you feel you _must_ make a boxplot, perhaps truncate the whisker at 0, and explain in a footnote.

Answer (score 1):

Never plot a box-whisker plot beyond min and max of data. Upper and lower bound are just used to find out outliers and extreme outliers. In this case you have to take lower bound as 172. You can use MATLAB command : `boxplot(x)` to check the same rule.